# How configure rest service and rest client to serialize java.util.Date when date is value in the Map<String,Object>

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey rest service. My resource object takes a Object as shown below as post parameter. From the client side
I am setting key values pair in properties field of my input object. One of the k,v pairs were (key,value)=("timestamp",new java.util.Date()). Once I have InputObject ready, I use json to serialize the data and send to RestService

when the request is received by my rest resource, I am getting the value corresponding to the key timestamp as a long.

I wanted to know if it is possible some how to get back value as java.util.Date e.g some kind of configuration or overridding capability in jersey
I am interested in standard way of handling this problem, there are few hacks that I know, I would apply them if only std way is not possible to achieve my requirement

```
public class InputObject {

private long id,
private Map<String,Object> map; 
// not adding the getters and setters
}
```

Following is what my resource object accepts.

```
@POST
@Path("/forceevent")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public AckValue sendEvent(InputObject request) 
{
    return AckValue.FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to parse from long to new Date object?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did that, it works however it is not my need. sine the date in coming in Map<String,Object>, so if I try to convert the date from long value, I need to be aware of keys. I was looking for something which converts the long value to Date without caring about the keys in the map.